# Problems reducing my AWS EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance on AWS using Centos 7.3.1611 and Plesk (set up through Amazon marketplace)

I have tried a number of times to reduce the size of my EBS volume. I keep running into problems.

I have managed to copy all the files over from the old server to the new using the instructions here (https://superuser.com/questions/1123799/how-to-decrease-size-the-ebs-root-volume-of-the-rhel-instance-in-aws) - as well as similar other guides.

The only difference is because I am using xfs instead of ext4 I was unable to do the e2label

When I attach the new volume to the instance as /dev/sda1 it does not load. I cannot connect to it using SSH and websites do not load.

I am at a loss now. I have tried so many times. I made a mistake making my initial EBS volume size way too big and it is costing me quite a bit of money every day.

can somebody please advise what I can do to find out what is going wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you wish to reduce the size? Is it just to save money? It's just 10c/GB/month, so you are probably spending more time than the benefit offers.

Comment: I do understand what you mean but there are other reasons. I want to reduce the volume by 200GB (which is nearly $300 per year) and also it is a learning experience. I want to be able to be able to do this if there are any problems at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has instructions on reducing an EBS volume [here](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/amazon-ebs-shink-vol).   Basically, like managing EBS volumes Amazon prefers that the volume be copied to a new volume.  For each step it is important to copy down the names of your volumes and instances so you know which is which as you proceed.

So would can create a new volume the size you want, say 10Gb, in the same availability zone. Attach both volumes to the same instance. Create a file system and mount directory on the new volume, then sync the files. Then unmount the smaller volume. Stop the instance.  Add the new small volume to the block device name you wrote down at the beginning. Then restart and verify everything is were you need it.

There are many ways to administer your EBS volumes, Management Console, CLI; that's good and bad.  There are still some actions that are done more effectively through the CLI.  Keeping accurate track of your storage needs is critical, you could be throwing money out the window.

If you want your new volume in a new region you will have to take another approach to copying the data, and it can be encrypted. Basic steps are similar: create a volume, create a snapshot, make sure you have a mount point on the new volume. One thing to member is that Amazon will not let you change volume encryption directly.  You would need to copy encrypted volume to unencrypted volume or the other way around. For more information on managing your AWS EBS volumes check out [this article](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/managing-ebs-volumes-in-aws-cloudhttps://cloud.netapp.com/blog/managing-ebs-volumes-in-aws-cloud) by NetApp.

P.S. yes there is a typo in Amazon's link,  :-)